# Sharing a macro across multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a simple macro which will work in different workbooks but only if the WORKSHEET has the same name. In the code below, the worksheet is called "TEMPLATE." How can I make this work regardless of the name of the worksheet?
This is for a number of divisions within a tournament; each worksheet represents a scoresheet for a division with several competitors. At the end the division, the macro is designed to sort the competitors into 1st place, 2nd place, etc. I'm sure there's an easy solution, but I am not a coder!

```
    Sub SORTSCORE2()
'
' SORTSCORE2 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B8:B26"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A7:M26")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How would it "know" what sheet it should be running on?  If it's always the active sheet then replace `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TEMPLATE")` with `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Thank you so much. Initial experiments were successful! You've saved me hours of work with a simple, elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` if you want to run one sheet at a time

Alternatively you can use a loop of all sheets in the workbook

```
Sub SORTSCORE2()

' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C

Dim Sheet as WorkSheet
For Each Sheet in ActiveWorkbook
    Sheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Sheet.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range( _
        "B8:B26"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With Sheet.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A7:M26")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your looping code without success (I'm sure I'm doing something wrong); not a problem, I only wanted the macro to work on the active sheet. HOWEVER, your first answer using ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet worked perfectly. I did a Google search on this particular issue with no success; your solution is simple, elegant, and it works. You saved me a lot of work! Thank you.